# When @objc and @nonobjc write before method and variable in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift2, swift3

When I declare `static` parameter in extension of class then I have to write `@nonobjc` before variable like:

```
@nonobjc static let test = "test"
```

and sometimes I have to write `@objc` before method, so what is use of `@objc` and `@nonobjc` in Swift.

Can anyone help me for this problem?

Comment: [Swift Language Reference - Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is explained in the [Apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html) about Objective-C - Swift interoperability:

> When you use the @objc(name) attribute on a Swift class, the class is
>   made available in Objective-C without any namespacing. As a result,
>   this attribute can also be useful when migrating an archivable
>   Objective-C class to Swift. Because archived objects store the name of
>   their class in the archive, you should use the @objc(name) attribute
>   to specify the same name as your Objective-C class so that older
>   archives can be unarchived by your new Swift class.
>
> Conversely, Swift also provides the @nonobjc attribute, which makes a
>   Swift declaration unavailable in Objective-C. You can use it to
>   resolve circularity for bridging methods and to allow overloading of
>   methods for classes imported by Objective-C. If an Objective-C method
>   is overridden by a Swift method that cannot be represented in
>   Objective-C, such as by specifying a parameter to be a variable, that
>   method must be marked @nonobjc.

To summarize, use @objc when you want to expose a Swift attribute to Objective-C without a namespace . Use @nonobjc if you want to keep the attribute available and accessible only in Swift code.

Comment: Isn't this now limited to "overriding" the `@objcMembers` annotation of a class when declaring an extension we don't want to expose to Objective-C?

Answer (score 4):

*(Addendum/additional official details to [@bontoJR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41036133/4573247) well summarizing answer)*

From the [Swift Language Reference - Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html) [**emphasis mine**]:

> **`objc`**
>
> Apply this attribute to any declaration that **can be represented in
>   Objective-C** — for example, non-nested classes, protocols, nongeneric
>   enumerations (constrained to integer raw-value types), properties and
>   methods (including getters and setters) of classes and protocols,
>   initializers, deinitializers, and subscripts. The `objc` attribute tells
>   the compiler that **a declaration is available to use in Objective-C
>   code**.
>
> ...
>
> **`nonobjc`**
>
> Apply this attribute to a method, property, subscript, or initializer
>   declaration **to suppress an implicit `objc` attribute**. The `nonobjc`
>   attribute tells the compiler **to make the declaration unavailable in
>   Objective-C code**, even though it is possible to represent it in
>   Objective-C.
>
> ...

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find more details in this [Swift Documentation : InteractingWithObjective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html)

As an answer of your question, overview from attached link is as below.

> **@objc** : You can use attribute to change the name of a class, property, method, enumeration type, or enumeration case declaration in
>   your interface as it’s exposed to Objective-C code.

**Example** : if the name of your Swift class contains a character that isn’t supported by Objective-C, you can provide an alternative name to use in Objective-C.

> **@nonobjc** : It makes a swift declaration unavailable in Objective-C. You can use it to resolve circularity for bridging
>   methods and to allow overloading of methods for classes imported by
>   Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

**@objc**

When you mark a piece of code with **@objc**, you are essentially saying that it **can be recognized and used by Objective-C code.** This is useful when you're working with a mixed codebase that includes both Swift and Objective-C, or when you need to interface with Objective-C frameworks or libraries.

**@nonobjc**

The **@nonobjc** attribute is used in Swift to indicate that a certain declaration should not be exposed to Objective-C. It is essentially the opposite of @objc. When you mark a declaration with @nonobjc, you're specifying that it should not be accessible from Objective-C code