# Is there a Swift attribute, such as @nonobjc designed for protocols?

Tags: swift, language-interoperability

I want to write a PAT and I don't care about Obj-C interoperability. The [@nonobjc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41036133/13074633) attribute sounds perfect but its designed for variables and methods only. 
Anything similar for hiding protocols from Obj-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstood what the `@nonobjc` attribute is for:

From the [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html):

> ### nonobjc
>
> Apply this attribute to a method, property, subscript, or initializer
>   declaration ***to suppress an implicit `objc` attribute.***

If you scroll further down the page, it tells you what will have an implicit `objc` attribute on them:

> The compiler implicitly adds the `objc` attribute to subclasses of any class defined in Objective-C. However, the subclass must not be generic, and must not inherit from any generic classes. [...] The objc attribute is also implicitly added in the following cases:
>
> - The declaration is an override in a subclass, and the superclass’s declaration has the objc attribute.
> - The declaration satisfies a requirement from a protocol that has the `objc` attribute.
> - The declaration has the `IBAction`, `IBSegueAction`, `IBOutlet`, `IBDesignable`, `IBInspectable`, `NSManaged`, or `GKInspectable`
>     attribute.

This does not include protocols, so protocols are never implicitly exposed to Objective-C. This means that you don't need the `nonobjc` attribute on protocols to suppress implicit `objc`s on protocols. Protocols, by default, are not exposed to Objective-C, unless you mark them with `@objc`.

Comment: This is the direction I was heading. I was trying to provide a default implementation that handled UITableViewDataSource. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39604189/13074633